# Сбор логов с серверов

Tags: сервер, логирование

Задача такая:
Есть несколько серверов. На каждом из них пишутся логи, а именно:

1. лог apache
2. лог apache для конкретного виртуального хоста
3. собственные логи, которые пишет программа и складывает в определенную папку

Эти логи нужно периодически просматривать. Но очень неудобно заходить на каждый сервер и проверять их вручную.
Возможно существуют какие-либо решения для отслеживания логов на серверах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите в сторону [splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) оно предназначено для управления логами, так же это можно решить с помощью [syslogd](http://www.k-max.name/linux/syslogd-and-logrotate/), обычно в крупных сетях используется отделная машина/сервер для хранения логов, на котором крутится syslogd и прям в него другие сервера пишут логи. Таким образом снижается нагрузка на disk i/o и решается проблема с местом на серверах.

Comment: Спасибо за совет!

Comment: Это все "тяжелая артиллерия". 

Если подходить проще, то достаточно `ncat` и `bash` (обратите внимание на  `/dev/tcp/HOST/PORT` в нем), ну м.б. еще `expect` и `tk` для простых окошек.

Comment: да по отношению к splunk, syslogd это вполне себе стандартный демон в никсах, но про инфраструктуру мы ничего не знаем, в конце концов можно по крону настроить rsync и синкать логи в одно место и там дальше разбирать.